# I want to use mailcatcher for confirmable in devise gem but get this when i am runing bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable, mailcatcher

Can anyone help me with this i am using rails 7.0.2.3

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rack (= 2.2.3)
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 7.0.2, >= 7.0.2.3) was resolved to 7.0.2.3, which depends on
      actionpack (= 7.0.2.3) was resolved to 7.0.2.3, which depends on
        rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.2.0)
    mailcatcher (~> 0.8.2) was resolved to 0.8.2, which depends on
      rack (~> 1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mailcatcher is not supposed to be in your Gemfile, and you don't run it through bundle exec. I'm running v0.6.4 on a Rails 5 project with gem install mailcatcher and then mailcatcher.
Have you tried that?